# Image picker and firebase plugins supporting iOS, android and web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to migrate my existing flutter application to web. But while migrating app to web,I am facing issues regarding some plugins(i.e firebase and image picker) as that supports only iOS and android but not web. Is there any plugin or work around which supports all of the above platforms (i.e. iOS, android and web)? Is there any work around for this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be highly specific to the plugins that you are using.  It looks like there is some amount of discussion about how to proceed in order to make the plugins searchable by the platform that they support (web/android/ios/desktop) as well as creating a pubspec.yaml format to load specific plugins depending on the platform being used. (the schema is discussed [here (by user amirh)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10288)

Depending on what functionality that you're trying to get, there are some workarounds for auth and firestore web.  There are some discussions [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/40) about various methods to get around this issue.  HOWEVER....

... the flutter team has been very clear that there is still a long way to go for web development.  They have indicated that the current version of flutter is [still in beta, and not ready for production](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web), and that [flutter plugins are not ready for web use.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web)

So, workarounds exist, but they are highly specific (like [fp_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/fb_auth) for firebase authorization, and [unofficial firebase sdks](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/firebase_dart_sdk))